# Create a copy of a tensor and all of its dependencies in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to write a function that receives a logits layer as input and duplicates it and all of its dependent tensors and ops.

In other words, given a logits layer of some graph:
[image]

I want to turn it to this (without knowing the architecture of the net):
[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a bunch of graph rewrites implemented in [Grappler, TensorFlow's graph optimizer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers). That may be a reasonable place to look for graph rewriting examples, although it is possible to do graph rewrites from Python too.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I solved it with tf.contrib.copy_graph. I need to update this question. Thanks.